# simple_html_dom doesn't take data from some websites

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

simple_html_dom does not take data from some websites. 
For the website www.google.pl, it downloads the source of the page, 
but for other such as: gearbest.com, stooq.pl does not download any data.

```
require('simple_html_dom.php');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/"); //  work

/*
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.gearbest.com/"); // dont work
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stooq.pl/"); // dont work
*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($response);

echo $html;
```

What should I change in the code to receive data from websites?

Comment: If it works on some sites and some not, they probably have some protection against bots and don't want you to do what you're trying to do. it could also be that the sites contents are mainly loaded with javascript, which would never be executed if you load the site source without any js-engine to execute it.

Comment: for some time, the above code worked for these pages. Probably there may be some blockade, e.g. on IP. Could you check if this code works for you?

Download simple_html_dom: https://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/files/

Comment: verify `$response` or `strlen($response)` on each run.

Comment: I don't have time to setup your app and debug your code for you. You could simply create a server on something like Amazon, Digital Ocean, Heroku or something and test.

Answer (score 0):

> The root problem here (at least on my computer, maybe different with
>   your version...) is that site returns gzipped data, and it isn't being
>   uncompressed properly by php and curl before being passed to the dom
>   parser. If you are using php 5.4, you can use gzdecode and
>   file_get_contents to uncompress it yourself.
>
> ```
> <?php
>     // download the site
>     $data = file_get_contents("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=49776615757150035");
>     // decompress it (a bit hacky to strip off the gzip header)
>     $data = gzinflate(substr($data, 10, -8));
>     include("simple_html_dom.php");
>     // parse and use
>     $html = str_get_html($data);
>     echo $html->root->innertext();
> ```
>
> Note that this hack will not work on most sites. The main reason
>   underlying this seems to me that curl doesn't announce that it accepts
>   gzip data... but the web server on that domain doesn't pay attention
>   to that header, and gzips it anyway. Then neither curl nor php
>   actually checks the Content-Encoding header on the response, and
>   assumes it isn't gzipped so it passes it through without an error nor
>   calling gunzip. Bugs in both the server and the client here!
>
> For a more robust solution, maybe you can use curl to get the headers
>   and inspect them yourself to determine if you need to decompress it.
>   Or you can just use this hack for this site and the normal method for
>   others to keep things simple.
>
> It might still also help to set the character encoding on your output.
>   Add this before you echo anything to ensure the data you read isn't
>   recorrupted in the user's browser by being read as the wrong charset:
>
> ```
> header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
> ```

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 7.0.33. Your method does not work for me for gearbest.com. It works fine for other websites. Is there any other way / method that would work for me?